# Tangent bundle of Milnor manifold

Tags: vector-bundles, hypersurfaces

[image]As I have been studying about Milnor manifold defined above, I want to understand its tangent bundle structure. I could not find anything related to that anywhere.

I am aware of the fact that $H(m,n)$ is a fiber bundle over $\mathbb{R}P^m$ with fiber $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$.

It would be of great help if anyone can suggest the way to proceed or provide me with some materials where it has been done.

**Edit 1:**
After some research I found this  interesting result.

[image]

I just need to find the appropriate manipulation for the real case.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Could you define Milnor manifold (or include a link with a definition)? Also what is that you want to know about its tangent bundle?

Comment: I have added the definition, My question is How can one find the tangent bundle? @IgorBelegradek

Comment: I see that a lot of information about Milnor manifolds is in "Classification of homotopy real Milnor manifolds by HK Mukerjee", https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81993157.pdf and it is complicated. Usually, by "find a bundle" people mean expressing it in terms of known bundles. One could try to show that the bundle is trivial (seems unlikely). Another case is when there is a complete classification of such bundles, and you are able to pinpoint where your bundle fits into the classification. Complete classifications are rare. I would start by going through the literature on Milnor's manifolds.

Comment: Specifically, I would start from p.4 of  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.7475.pdf which describes the Milnor manifold as the projectization of some explicit vector bundle.

Comment: That actually makes sense, let me go through your second link, thanks for your time @IgorBelegradek